# UWP: Waiting for invokeScriptAsync to be done

Tags: javascript, c#, windows, asynchronous

I need to be sure that my Play() function gets called after the text is added to the webview with a javascript function (AddToPage). Does the await keyword makes sure that the javascript function is fully executed, or does it only wait until the call has been made?

```
    private async void AddChunk(ChunkEventArgs chunkargs)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("AddChunk called: " + chunkargs.Text);

        await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,async () =>
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(chunkargs.Text))
            {
                string text = App.chunkparser.ParseChunk(chunkargs.Text);

                Debug.WriteLine("calling addparsedchunk");
                CurrentDocument.AddParsedChunk(App.chunkparser.ElementFromChunk);

                await _webView.InvokeScriptAsync("AddToPage", new string[] { text  });

                if (App.settings.AutoPlay && !SpeechControl.IsSpeaking)
                    Play();
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`InvokeScriptAsync` waits until the script ends.

- It returns the result of the script, which is only possible if the script has ended
- The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) says `Your app might appear unresponsive while scripts are running. Handle the LongRunningScriptDetected event to interrupt a long-running script.`, which clearly indicates that the method waits for the script completion